# How can I put a line break in a Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

How to put line break in controller? or View?, example:

```
Robison F. - Robison 1    
Robison F. - Robison 2
Robison F. - Robison 3
Robison F. - Robison 4
....
```

```
<div class="modal-body">
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <div class="card" style="width: 1118rem;">
                 <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Título do card</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Subtitulo do card</h6>
                      <p class="card-text">{{$item->atualizacao}}</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
             </div>
</div>
```

[image]

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    
    $seguro = seguro::find($id);
    
    $seguro->atualizacao = $seguro->atualizacao .'    '.Auth()->user()->name .' - '. $request->atualizacao;
    $seguro->update();

    return redirect()->route('segindex');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not at all clear what you're asking. Please see [ask] and revise.

Comment: You'd use a `<br>`. HTML doesn't care about line breaks in text.

Comment: Yes, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

on youR view , make

```
 <p class="card-text">{{$item->atualizacao}}</p>
```

to

```
 <p class="card-text">{!!$item->atualizacao!!}</p>
```

and on your controller, make

```
   $seguro->atualizacao = $seguro->atualizacao .'    '.Auth()->user()->name .' - '. $request->atualizacao;
```

to

```
   $seguro->atualizacao = $seguro->atualizacao .'  </br>  '.Auth()->user()->name .' - '. $request->atualizacao;
```

Comment: </br> Robison F. -
</br> Robison F. - TESTE ATUALIZAÇÃO 1
</br> Robison F. -
</br> Robison F. -

Comment: when displayed using {!!$var!!}  instead of {{$var}}, the tags will take effect and you get desired output